# mpirun noticed that process rank 1 with PID 0 on node X540UV exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault)

Tags: c++, mpi

I'm a beginner MPI programming. I want multiplication 2d vector using MPI.I write this program follows,when I define 2d matrix uses mat_a[][] ,mat_b[][]I don't receive this problem but I define using 2d vector recevied such problem:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
#include<mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<curses.h>
#include<vector>
#define NUM_ROWS_A 12 //rows of input [A]
#define NUM_COLUMNS_A 12 //columns of input [A]
#define NUM_ROWS_B 12 //rows of input [B]
#define NUM_COLUMNS_B 12 //columns of input [B]
#define MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG 1 //tag for messages sent from master to slaves
#define SLAVE_TO_MASTER_TAG 4 //tag for messages sent from slaves to master
void makeAB(); //makes the [A] and [B] matrixes
void printArray(); //print the content of output matrix [C];
int rank; //process rank
int size; //number of processes
int i, j, k; //helper variables
std::vector<std::vector<double> >mat_a(NUM_ROWS_A,std::vector<double>(NUM_COLUMNS_A)); //declare input [A]
std::vector<std::vector<double> >mat_b(NUM_ROWS_B, std::vector<double>(NUM_COLUMNS_B)); //declare input [B]
std::vector<std::vector<diuble> >mat_result(NUM_ROWS_A ,std::vector<double>(NUM_COLUMNS_B)); //declare output [C]
double start_time; //hold start time
double end_time; // hold end time
int low_bound; //low bound of the number of rows of [A] allocated to a slave
int upper_bound; //upper bound of the number of rows of [A] allocated to a slave
int portion; //portion of the number of rows of [A] allocated to a slave
MPI_Status status; // store status of a MPI_Recv
MPI_Request request; //capture request of a MPI_Isend
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); //initialize MPI operations
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank); //get the rank
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size); //get number of processes
    /* master initializes work*/
    if (rank == 0) {
        makeAB();
        start_time = MPI_Wtime();
        for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {//for each slave other than the master
            portion = (NUM_ROWS_A / (size - 1)); // calculate portion without master
            low_bound = (i - 1) * portion;
            if (((i + 1) == size) && ((NUM_ROWS_A % (size - 1)) != 0)) {//if rows of [A] cannot be equally divided among slaves
                upper_bound = NUM_ROWS_A; //last slave gets all the remaining rows
            } else {
                upper_bound = low_bound + portion; //rows of [A] are equally divisable among slaves
            }
            //send the low bound first without blocking, to the intended slave
            MPI_Isend(&low_bound, 1, MPI_INT, i, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
            //next send the upper bound without blocking, to the intended slave
            MPI_Isend(&upper_bound, 1, MPI_INT, i, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG + 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
            //finally send the allocated row portion of [A] without blocking, to the intended slave
            MPI_Isend(&mat_a[low_bound][0], (upper_bound - low_bound) * NUM_COLUMNS_A, MPI_DOUBLE, i, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG + 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
        }
    }
    //broadcast [B] to all the slaves
    MPI_Bcast(&mat_b, NUM_ROWS_B*NUM_COLUMNS_B, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    /* work done by slaves*/
    if (rank > 0) {
        //receive low bound from the master
        MPI_Recv(&low_bound, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        //next receive upper bound from the master
        MPI_Recv(&upper_bound, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG + 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        //finally receive row portion of [A] to be processed from the master
        MPI_Recv(&mat_a[low_bound][0], (upper_bound - low_bound) * NUM_COLUMNS_A, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG + 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        for (i = low_bound; i < upper_bound; i++) {//iterate through a given set of rows of [A]
            for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLUMNS_B; j++) {//iterate through columns of [B]
                for (k = 0; k < NUM_ROWS_B; k++) {//iterate through rows of [B]
                    mat_result[i][j] += (mat_a[i][k] * mat_b[k][j]);
                }
            }
        }
        //send back the low bound first without blocking, to the master
        MPI_Isend(&low_bound, 1, MPI_INT, 0, SLAVE_TO_MASTER_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
        //send the upper bound next without blocking, to the master
        MPI_Isend(&upper_bound, 1, MPI_INT, 0, SLAVE_TO_MASTER_TAG + 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
        //finally send the processed portion of data without blocking, to the master
        MPI_Isend(&mat_result[low_bound][0], (upper_bound - low_bound) * NUM_COLUMNS_B, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, SLAVE_TO_MASTER_TAG + 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
    }
    /* master gathers processed work*/
    if (rank == 0) {
        for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {// untill all slaves have handed back the processed data
            //receive low bound from a slave
            MPI_Recv(&low_bound, 1, MPI_INT, i, SLAVE_TO_MASTER_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            //receive upper bound from a slave
            MPI_Recv(&upper_bound, 1, MPI_INT, i, SLAVE_TO_MASTER_TAG + 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            //receive processed data from a slave
            MPI_Recv(&mat_result[low_bound][0], (upper_bound - low_bound) * NUM_COLUMNS_B, MPI_DOUBLE, i, SLAVE_TO_MASTER_TAG + 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        }
        end_time = MPI_Wtime();
        printf("\nRunning Time = %f\n\n", end_time - start_time);
        printArray();
    }
    MPI_Finalize(); //finalize MPI operations
    return 0;
}
void makeAB()
{
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS_A; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLUMNS_A; j++) {
            mat_a[i][j] = i + j;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS_B; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLUMNS_B; j++) {
            mat_b[i][j] = i*j;
        }
    }
}
void printArray()
{
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS_A; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLUMNS_A; j++)
            printf("%8.2f  ", mat_a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS_B; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLUMNS_B; j++)
            printf("%8.2f  ", mat_b[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS_A; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLUMNS_B; j++)
            printf("%8.2f  ", mat_result[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

I am compiling program using,
mpic++ multi.cpp -o multi
and run it with,
mpirun -np 3 multi
but I received this error,

```
    [X540UV:08026] *** Process received signal ***
    [X540UV:08028] *** Process received signal ***
    [X540UV:08028] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
    [X540UV:08028] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
    [X540UV:08028] Failing at address: 0xf6e680
    [X540UV:08027] *** Process received signal ***
    [X540UV:08027] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
    [X540UV:08027] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
    [X540UV:08027] Failing at address: 0xf6e680
    [X540UV:08027] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x354b0)[0x7f1a9cae74b0]
    [X540UV:08027] [ 1] multi3[0x401cfa]
    [X540UV:08027] [ 2] multi3[0x4012d5]
    [X540UV:08027] [ 3] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f1a9cad2830]
    [X540UV:08027] [ 4] multi3[0x400e79]
    [X540UV:08027] *** End of error message ***
    [X540UV:08028] [ 0] [X540UV:08026] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
    [X540UV:08026] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
    [X540UV:08026] Failing at address: 0xf6e680
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x354b0)[0x7fd43be274b0]
    [X540UV:08026] [ 0] [X540UV:08028] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x354b0)[0x7fde584744b0]
    [X540UV:08026] [ 1] multi3[0x401cfa]
    [X540UV:08026] [ 2] multi3[0x4012d5]
    [ 1] [X540UV:08026] [ 3] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fde5845f830]
    [X540UV:08026] [ 4] multi3[0x400e79]
    [X540UV:08026] *** End of error message ***
    multi3[0x401cfa]
    [X540UV:08028] [ 2] multi3[0x4012d5]
    [X540UV:08028] [ 3] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fd43be12830]
    [X540UV:08028] [ 4] multi3[0x400e79]
    [X540UV:08028] *** End of error message ***
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mpirun noticed that process rank 1 with PID 0 on node X540UV exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
```

Comment: `MPI_Bcast(&mat_b,...`. This is totally wrong. `mat_b` is an object/instance of `std::vector<...`. You likely need to send matrix elements, but since you have a vector of vectors, the elements are not stored in a contiguous memory location. You need to store them in a 1D vector, possibly with some 2D accessors. Alternatively, use Boost::MPI, which can send containers over MPI (just note that it will be likely slower than sending a 1D vector).

Comment: @Daniel Langr,why cann't send matrix element using MPI_Bcact vector<vector<double>>mat_b ?what's problem that there isn't in 1d vector , this code using mat_b[][] working correctly but i want to use vector<vector<double>>mat_b because in main program the size of mat_b change in repeats

Comment: Because `MPI_Bcast` requests the sent data to be stored in a contiguous memory location. Try to figure out how elements of a vector-of-vectors are stored. BTW, `&mat_b` returns a pointer to the (outer) vector object itself, not to its elements. Learn some basics about vectors.

Comment: You can broadcast a vector-of-vectors, but not in a single step. Instead, you need to broadcast elements of each inner vector separately. Something as `for (const auto& v : mat_b) MPI_Bcast(v.data(), v.size(), MPI_DOUBLE,...)`.

Comment: If you want to do efficient MPI communications, you should use 2D arrays (e.g. `double a[10][10]`) instead of jagged arrays (such as `double **a` or C++ vectors of vectors). An other C++'ish option is to use a higher level library such as boost.MPI that features multidimensional arrays https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

Comment: @ Daniel Langr,@ Gilles Gouaillardet , thanks to your response